# How can I know if a certain conference is worth attending and submitting my papers to?

Tags: conference

As a PhD student in the field of information science, I want to find conferences to submit my papers to. How can I search for suitable target conferences? How can I know if a conference is of high quality?

Comment: Your question title is about which conference is worth attending. Your question body is about which conference to submit your papers to. Please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

1. Talk to your advisor.
2. Look at the conferences that published work you are citing.
3. Talk to your advisor.
4. Look up people whose work you rely on. Which conferences are they publishing in?
5. Talk to your advisor.

You may notice a pattern there. Actually, work you are citing is possibly a bit more high-impact than your own work, which is why point 2 might lead you to aim a little too high, where your work might have a higher chance of being rejected. Which is why points 1, 3 and 5 are so important.

If there are other people around working on similar topics (e.g., Ph.D. candidates that have been around a little longer), you may want to ask them, too.

Comment: I really wish there would be a more reliable all-encompassing website that'd show a list of reputed conferences and journals, and more metadata and tools which helps people filter down to make a selection.

Comment: @Nav - knowledgeable advice from known good sources (e.g. your advisor) are much better than any all-encompassing website. Not just because your particular subfield has a particular view, but the all-encompassing website will have fake reviews or will be threatened with lawsuits as Beale was back in the day.